# Get the height/width in % using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I dynamically resize some elements using jQuery.

In most of the cases, it's going well, i call `$(selector).css('height');` to get the height/width values or `$(selector).height();`.

It generally provides me the value in `px`, even if i setted it up in `%` in my stylesheet.

But sometimes, it returns the value in `%`, so i am wondering, is there a way to be sure to get the value in `px` ? How to "prevent" the format ?

Comment: Can you provide an example (like a jsfiddle) of when you would get a % returned from jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I take this back - I'm not sure if jQuery ever returns a % value, even if you specify it in your CSS - inline or otherwise (although I will leave my original answer intact).

Can you provide an example of when you would get a % value returned?

**ORIGINAL**

`.css()` will get you the value that you applied directly to your element:

```
  <div style="height: 75%;">
```

`.height()` get's the height of the element in the DOM itself - always in pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use

```
$(selector).css('height');
```

to get pixel values. It returns the determined CSS, which is likely why you are receiving the percentage values returned. Use

```
$(selector).height();
```

for pixel values exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/height/):

> .height() returns a unit-less pixel value

If you actually wanted %, you'd have to make the calculation by measuring the document height as well.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var a = $(window).height();
var b = $('#div').height();
```

the height in percent can be calculated as:

```
(b / a)*100
```